# Effect of the before months

Tags: articles

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> He has been absent **for the past** few months.

> He has been absent **for    past** few months.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first sentence is grammatical.

Using *past* and *few* together sets a very particular and definite time span, so the definite article is obligatory.

There are cases where it's not with other prepositions and adjectives:

*in recent months*

*for a few months*

*past months had been different*

Etc.

However, the combination of *for*, *past* and *few* in your example makes the definite article necessary.